# How can I force JMeter slaves to use a specific network interface?

Tags: networking, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

My computer has 2 network interfaces which are connected in 2 different networks and when I start the JMeter slave the wrong network interface is automatically chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force network interface to use for both client and server sides of things by setting the following property:

```
java.rmi.server.hostname=169.168.167.166
```

It can also be passed as a command-line argument to JMeter startup script being prefixed by `-D` as

```
jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=169.168.167.166
```

References:

- [Remote(Distributed) Testing Guide](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)